# iOS Storyboard Design and Cocos2d+Box2d Objects

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, storyboard, box2d

In my iOS (iPad) app I want to design my view in Storyboard. This view will contain buttons, UIImageViews (with animatied images most of them with onTapGestureRecognizers), sounds, Text etc. I want above all these to have some objects created with cocos2d+Box2d that will have physics (they will be floating around according to accelerometer etc).

Is all this possible? Can I have my main design made in storyboard and some objects made with cocos2d+box2d and all user interactions working?

Any working example - tutorial?

Comment: In theory this is possible. You need to use the created CCGLView (or EAGLView depending on the cocos2d version) and embed it inside the storyboard via code (See application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method on a cocos2D example). You could very well just add IBActions that will trigger adding other stuff on cocos. I'll try to make an example and post it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the info. An example would be really useful.

Comment: @AndresC If you have any working example it would be really helpful since I have managed to make the box2d work in a separate view but I want it to work over an existing storyboard view. thanks!!